# How to display values from array in JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to display all values from array categories, but I always got [object object] or undefined.
Here is code in last lines if statement, there is that problem in part between bracket [] when I want to call categories and type of categories is Object:

```
  const urlKeys = [...new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.keys()];

  let categories = [];

  let count = urlKeys.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
    categories.push({ type: paramsFromUrl.get('category' + i) })
  }  //Here I push elements in categories

  if (urlKeys[0] === 'allCategories') {
    document.getElementById('notice').innerText = "All categories included: [" + categories + "]";
    return viewsjs.createRestaurantCards(filterjs.findRestaurantsByCategory(await restaurantsjs.loadRestaurantsJSON(), categories));
  } //Here is problem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`categories` is an array of objects. If you want to convert that to a string, you need to do `JSON.stringify`

```js
"All categories included: " + JSON.stringify(categories);
```

---

If you only want to display the type and not the whole object, then:

```js
"All categories included: [" + categories.map(obj => obj.type) + "]";
```

Comment: Thank u. This works!

Answer (score 1):

You can’t concatenate an Array directly into a String; it’s simply not the way it works. Seems like you need `join()`, which would return another String that you can successfully concatenate into your broader string to write into the DOM:

```
document.getElementById('notice').innerText = "All categories included: [" + categories.join(", ") + "]";
```

Comment: Thank u, but this does not help, I still get result [object Object], [object Object],...[object Object]

Comment: JS has type coersion, so it'll join automatically. It is better to explicitly declare it, but it isn't causing the problem here.

Comment: @StephenK Then you’ve left some critical information out of your post; what type of data is contained in `categories`…?

Comment: @esqew  console.log(typeof (categories)) when I type this I get Object